# EventTrigger based on several other controls being given focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have this `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="buttonStudentPicker" Content="Student Picker" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2,10,2,10" BorderThickness="0,5,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ToggleButton.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </ToggleButton.LayoutTransform>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=buttonBibleReadingMain, Path=IsFocused, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

I have two related issues. Firstly, I actually have several elements on the interface that I would like to cause this button to toggle on. At the moment I can only work out how to do this based on one element, since I can't have all the elements focused at the same time. Essentially:

```
If button a or button b or button c has just been clicked
    Toggle student picker button to true
```

The related issue is that, whilst I have it working for one control, and the toggle fires, the moment I put focus on another control the toggle switches off. I don't really want that. Ideally, if the toggle was already off when the button gained focus, then yes, it should toggle off again. But fi it was already visible, it should not toggle off.

Ideally I would use `MultiDataTrigger` but as I found out all conditions must be true. From [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXytf3tcrNAhVlCMAKHSxID9AQFgg1MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F7889009%2Fmultidatatrigger-or-statement&usg=AFQjCNHHiRQ8s2Mq0b3hKs7BrLGc3iFbDw&sig2=MEoKTCG5JI4GKTjZEgwukQ) I decided to do a set of DataTriggers:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="buttonStudentPicker" Content="Student Picker" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2,10,2,10" BorderThickness="0,5,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ToggleButton.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </ToggleButton.LayoutTransform>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=buttonBibleReadingMain, Path=IsPressed, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=buttonBibleReadingClass1, Path=IsPressed, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=buttonBibleReadingClass2, Path=IsPressed, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

I thought I would try `IsPressed` to see if it works and it does but that is not the right property to use.

I just can't get it right. If they click the button, trigger the toggle to true. But don't do anything else.

Clear as mud?

Update: If I add a click handler to my buttons. Example:

```
<Button Name="buttonBibleReadingMain" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" Click="buttonBibleReadingMain_Click">
    <Image Source="Images/AssignmentTypeBibleReading.png" Margin="2"/>
</Button>
```

And put this is code-behind:

```
private void buttonBibleReadingMain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    buttonStudentPicker.IsChecked = true;
}
```

It does what as want. As the button is clicked, it ensures the panel is now visible. And the panel will stay visible for as long as I want. But I would need to do this for each of my controls that I want to force the panel to display.

Comment: What if you click a button and the togglebutton is already checked? it should uncheck or do nothing?

Comment: @Kirenenko at this point in time I feel that all I want to do is trigger to switch the panel on by setting the toggle to true. It will be up to the user to switch it back off.

Comment: Ok, then I think that you should go with the code behind. You can use the same click event for the 3 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `MultiDataTrigger` working like an OR instead of AND, because of this:

> (A and B) <=> ¬(¬A or ¬B)

**Applied to your code:**

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=buttonBibleReadingMain, Path=IsPressed, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=buttonBibleReadingClass1, Path=IsPressed, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=buttonBibleReadingClass2, Path=IsPressed, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="false"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

So you invert all the true values to false, and set the default value of your tooglebutton.IsChecked to true. That way, you will only have your toogle button unchecked if every button is unpressed.

Comment: Thanks. But this is still not what I want I am afraid. I am about to update my question.